# Double integral of $\frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates, iterated-integrals

I'm trying to crack an integral problem **whose answer has been lost**:

$$ I:=\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_\sqrt{1-x^2}^\sqrt{3-x^2}\frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx+\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\int_x^\sqrt{3-x^2}\frac{x}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx$$

Judging from its form, I guess the method of polar coordinates might do the trick. Then I made a drawing to help find the limits of integration:

[image]

In this drawing, the left one is responsible for the first integral while the right one helps us take care of the second integral. With this drawing, I transformed the original question into one that reads:
$$ I=\int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{r=1}^{r=\sqrt{3}}\frac{r\cos\theta}{1+r^2}rdrd\theta+\int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}}\int_{r=\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{2}}}^{r=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\cos\theta}\frac{r\cos\theta}{1+r^2}rdrd\theta$$

As it looks quite ugly, I have little confidence in what I just obtained. Does anyone get the same result? Thank you.

Comment: why it looks ugly? The integrals are separable (don't know if it's the right term)

Comment: If you add the two integrals you get an integral over the region 
$1 \le r \le \sqrt{3},  \, \frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: @JanG Hello, what do you mean by adding the two integrals? Is it possible to glue the two regions together? Thank you.

Comment: Since the integrand is the same we can glue the two regions together. The union will be 
$1 \le r \le \sqrt{3},  \, \frac{\pi}{4} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ (polar coordinates).

Comment: @JanG I see, you are integrating over an eighth of the annulus! My drawing is so rough that I couldn't understand what you meant at first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JanG's valuable comment, we can see
$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{r=1}^{r=\sqrt{3}}\frac{r\cos\theta}{1+r^2}rdrd\theta=\left[\int_{1}^{\sqrt{3}}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+r^2}\right)dr\right]\cdot\left[\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\theta d\theta\right]\\
&=\left[r-\tan^{-1}r\right]_{1}^{\sqrt{3}}\cdot\left[\sin\theta\right]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\left[(\sqrt 3-1)-(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{4})\right]\cdot\left(1-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right).
\end{align}$$
The computation above suggests my original result will differ from the actual value by an extra integral (the second one).